# Switching Database in Eloquent Based On User's Roles

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, eloquent

Hello in my lumen app I have created several users I would like to use to perform test transactions live on my server, currently test db transactions are mixed with actual records which is a real pain when removing.

What I want to do is check the user when they perform an action if they are a test user it should switch to my test_db and save the data there instead.  I would like to know how this can be done, is there a way to do this in the model so that it selects database to save based on logged in user's role?

Comment: How are you defining a test user?  Typically you would have a test/dev environment configured separately to your live environment.  If you do run tests on a live environment, you need something that allows you to distinguish a test user from a live user.

Comment: Roles.  I have a role called Test.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a middleware for this and conditionally set the database config based on the role.

```
If (auth()->user->role === 'test') {
    config(['database.connection.default' => [...test connection config]]);
}
```

Do this early in the request lifecycle.

Comment: Great! This looks the right solution to my problem, will check it out and see! :D

Comment: I've used this approach in several production applications. It's proven to be quite an elegant and reliable solution. Should work well for you too =D

Answer (score 1):

In your model you can define which db to use for that model;

```
 protected $connection = 'connection1';
```

Or if you're using multiple connection during run time on the controller, on your model set up a function to change the connection

```
public function changeConnection($conn)
{
   $this->connection = $conn;
}
```

and in the controller you can do:

```
if($user->role=='test'){
      $user->changeConnection('connection2');
}
```

Another solution is to use middleware